# Export all your activities, favorites, comments and upvotes from all Stack Exchange sites

Tags: feature-request, export, downloads, activity, backup

Is it possible to download all pages, that you committed any efforts?

I would like to have a downloaded folder that I can use offline, where all pages from my Profile site are linked, especially all sites that are reachable via the tab **Activity**.

Maybe this would be possible with a download-tool like `wget` and use the Network Profile Page as a start and from there follow all Sites you have an account and download all links in the Activity tab there.

I looked at http://data.stackexchange.com but there I could only find to export all my questions. which is way less then all my activity. And those exports are not as complete like they were if I would save the whole pages where the question is shown. A lot of data is missing there.

If there is no solution already available I would start to program such a tool with `wget`.

Comment: Do you know http://data.stackexchange.com  ?